# Correct way to execute a function in Web3 to avoid "invalid address"?

Tags: web3js

I am executing a function with Web3 like this:

```
MyContract.deployed().then(function (contractInstance) {    
      return contractInstance.MyFunction(parameter1, parameter2, { gas: 200000, from: web3.eth.accounts[0] })
    })
```

This works fine running the app on http://localhost:8080 with Chrome in incognito (so there's no MetaMask, which I have installed) - so the `web3.eth.accounts[0]` that executes the function will be the account I setup in Geth.

However, if I run the app in a normal Chrome window, where MetaMask will be active (thus it'll be using a different account) the following error will occur:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid address

Removing the web3.eth.accounts[0] part, so I run the function like this:

```
return contractInstance.SetMessage(key, string1, string2, string3, string4, { gas: 200000})
```

Also fails. How should this be done correctly?

Comment: I'm running this on the ropsten test network for now if that's relevant

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `geth` installed, I'd suggest connecting the `Metamask` to your `geth` instance running on http://localhost:8545. There is an option for that in `Metamask` in the list of available networks.

Comment: I get the invalid address error whether I have the ropsten network selected in MetaMask or localhost:8545

Comment: And what account does the Metamask UI show when you are connected to `localhost`? Is it the same as web3.eth.accounts[0]?

Comment: MetaMask doesn't seem to connect to localhost:8545 when it's the ropsten test network running in Geth (my command for connecting to ropsten is something like "geth --testnet --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*""), only when I have a private blockchain running